# React navigation without navigation prop, 'dispatch undefined'

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In my app I set up my navigation with React-Navigation without navigation props like this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

However, when I try to call `NavigationService.navigate('LoginScreen');`
from `componentDidMount()` I get 'dispatch undefined'.

When I call the same function from the `onTap` inside `render()`, I navigate as expected.

Code:

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        NavigationService.navigate('LoginScreen'); // does not work
    }
    //works at "onPress"
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('LoginScreen')}>SplashScreen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `withNavigation`. Like this:

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'
class SplashScreen extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen'); // Change it
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')}>SplashScreen</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default withNavigation(SplashScreen) // export component like this
```

[withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html) is a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) supplied by the `react-navigation` library that wraps your component to pass the required `navigation` prop.